# Why do I get the error "A valid Flask application was not obtained from..." when I use the flask cli to run my app?

Tags: flask, flask-cli

I try to use the flask cli to start my application, i.e. `flask run`. I use the `FLASK_APP` environment variable to point to my application, i.e. `export FLASK_APP=package_name.wsgi:app`

In my `wsgi.py` file, I create the app with a factory function, i.e. `app = create_app(config)` and my create_app method looks like this:

```
def create_app(config_object=LocalConfig):
    app = connexion.App(config_object.API_NAME,
                    specification_dir=config_object.API_SWAGGER_DIR,
                    debug=config_object.DEBUG)
    app.app.config.from_object(config_object)
    app.app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
    app.add_api(config_object.API_SWAGGER_YAML,
            strict_validation=config_object.API_SWAGGER_STRICT,
            validate_responses=config_object.API_SWAGGER_VALIDATE)
    app = register_extensions(app)
    app = register_blueprints(app)
    return app
```

However, the application doesn't start, I get the error:

> A valid Flask application was not obtained from "package_name.wsgi:app".

Why is this?

I can start my app normally when I use gunicorn, i.e. `gunicorn package_name.wsgi:app`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My create_app function didn't return an object of class `flask.app.Flask` but an object of class `connexion.apps.flask_app.FlaskApp`, because I am using the connexion framework.

In my wsgi.py file, I could simply set:

```
application = create_app(config)
app = application.app
```

I didn't even have to do `export FLASK_APP=package_name.wsgi:app` anymore, autodescovery worked if the `flask run` command was executed in the folder where the `wsgi.py` file is.

Answer (score 0):

```
application = create_app(config)
app = application.app
App = app.app
```

For me I just created another variable pointing to connexion.app.Flask type and I set the environ as below

```
export FLASK_APP= __main__:App
flask shell
```